# vim-closetag adds an extra ">"

Tags: vim, tags, neovim

DelimitMate collides with vim-closetag and adds an extra `>` when closing tags.

I fixed the above issue for `.erb` files with the fix mentioned here:
https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag/issues/40

```
au FileType html let b:delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),[:],{:}"
```

But the same fix did not work for a `.ejs` files, hence when adding the `.ejs` filetype to the config nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

If one looks at the file type in the nvim source code there is nothing for `.ejs`
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim

I solved my issue by changing the `.ejs` file type to an html filetype my nvim config like this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs set filetype=html
```

Now that my `.ejs` filetype is recognised as html filetype the same fix will work for my `.ejs` files.

My vim-closetag plugin config looks like this:

```
" These are the file extensions where this plugin is enabled.
let g:closetag_filenames = "*.xml,*.html,*.xhtml,*.phtml,*.php,*.erb"

" delimitMate colides with vim-closetag bug fix
au FileType eruby,xml,html,phtml,php,xhtml,js let b:delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),[:],{:}"

" These are the file types where this plugin is enabled.
let g:closetag_filetypes = 'html,xhtml,phtml,eruby'
```

This is how one can resolve the issue for all file types including `.erb`,`.ejs` and unrecognised file types.